# use variables created in the init of a class, into staticmethod functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class; which in its constructor, is assigning a variable.

I want to call this variable, from a function inside this class, which is a staticmethod. I can't seem to find the right way to do this.

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        myvariable = os.cwd()

    @staticmethod
    def myfunction(someparameter)

        print(myclass.myvariable)
        print(someparameter)
```

When I run the class from python, I get an error that `myvariable` does not exist

```
mytestclass = myclass
myclass.myfunction("foo")
```

I tried to use both `self.myvariable` and `myvariable`, but it does not make any difference. I didn't use `@classmethod` because if I would call `cls.myvariable`, I would not get that specific instance of myclass; and if I have multiple instances I may end up with issues.

Comment: "I want to call this variable, from a function inside this class, which is a staticmethod. I can't seem to find the right way to do this." You cannot access state from a static method, that is the *defining feature* of a staticmethod. Just use an instance method. staticmethods are practically pointless in Python, mostly just for organizational purposes

Comment: *Which* `myvariable` do you intend to access?  `__init__()` is called to initialize each instance of a class, and there can be any number of instances - and a `@staticmethod` has no connection to any particular instance.  (Note that you'd have to assign to `self.myvariable` for that to apply - as you've currently written it, `myvariable` is a local, and doesn't even exist after `__init__()` is finished.)

Comment: This might be an instance of an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the static variable?

Comment: @jasonharper I am trying to access the variable in the __init__, because I may have different instances of that class, so each one may be pointing at a different working directory.  I assumed that since I create myclass.myvariable in the __init__, that is also creating an instance at class/instance level, not just at the function level, but from your comment, it seems that the only way to do so is to create a variable in the class header, before the __init__

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not sure why you say that static methods are pointless in python. If I need just a function and not the whole class, and I don't want to make functions outside a class. I can change it as instance method; but my class may have another 40 functions in it; so wouldn't that impact performances?

Comment: @DaichiJameson not really an xy problem; I can create a variable and access it in a class method, but can't do the same with a static method, so I was asking how you do that. If that can't be done; and there is a motivation about that; then I will just change my code.Saying that it is an XY problem may imply that the question was not clearly understood, and as such, it has to be clarified further

Answer (score 0):

myVariable is only a temporary variable in this case, that only is visible in the `__init__` method, not even in other methods of the class. You could use myclass.myvariable also in the `__init__` method.

You can do it as follows. I also added an instance counter:

```
class myclass:
    counter= 0
    def __init__(self):
        myclass.myvariable = os.cwd()
        myclass.counter+= 1

    @staticmethod
    def myfunction(someparameter):
        print(myclass.myvariable)
        print(myclass.counter)
        print(someparameter)
```